# Get MMF for a story

Tags: rally

I feel like I am missing something here, but I would like to know the MMF for a story.  I tried pulling info from the Feature and PortfolioItem fields, but I only end up seeing the feature for the story.

```
Ext.create('Rally.data.WsapiDataStore', {
     model: 'User Story',
     autoLoad: true,
     fetch: ['Name', "Iteration", "PlanEstimate", "PortfolioItem", "Feature"],
     filters: filter,
     listeners: {
            load: function(store, records, success) {
                this._handleData(store);
            },
            scope: this
            }
     });
```

Is there a way I can use the feature to see what its MMF is?

Comment: I'm sorry, what does MMF mean/stand for?

Comment: Also, in regards to only seeing the feature - you will only see a PortfolioItem if it is a direct parent of the US - see my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18364905/confusion-about-hierarchicalrequirement-fields

Comment: MMF is minimum marketable feature.   IF you use portfolio manager as part of Rally you can divide things by Epic, MMF, and Feature.

Comment: Thanks for your post Tore, that answers a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Rally object model there is not an object called MMF.
If a Minimum Marketable Feature (MMF) is defined as the smallest piece of functionality which must be delivered in order for the customer to get value, that can be a Rally user story.

Comment: There is with portfolio manager.  It appears Rally does not fully support it through their entire API.

Comment: There is an example of an app with a grid of Features and their user stores:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17888510/rally-grid-of-features-and-rollups . Also, In WS API doc Parent field on a Hierarchical Requirement is expected to be a Hierarchical Requirement. It cannot be a Feature. Also, Feature field on a story is read-only,UserStories collection on Feature is read-only. If we want to add a user story as a child to a feature via API, we need to update PortfolioItem field on a story.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18087770/add-user-stories-as-children-to-feature/18087979#18087979